# Using dynamic variables in dplyr filter and summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to DRY up some of my R code, but I'm struggling to use dynamic variables in my function that uses Dplyr.

```
calc <- function(df, count_var, sample_var, pct_var) {
  df %>%
    filter_at(vars(count_var, sample_var), all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
    group_by(dated, device_category, path) %>%
    summarise(
      .groups = "keep",
      total_good := sum(df[[count_var]], na.rm = TRUE),
      sample_var := sum(df[[sample_var]], na.rm = TRUE),
      pct_var := total_good / df[[sample_var]]
    )
}

lcp <- calc(data, 'lcp_good_count', 'lcp_sample', 'lcp_good_pct')
```

How do I filter and then calculate the summary data using variable names passed to my function?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would expect to call the function and what it should output? At the moment we don't know whether you are passing strings, variable names, predicates, etc

Comment: Have a look at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html, e.g. if you pass a column name as a string you could use e.g. `.data[[count_var]]`.

Comment: @AllanCameron added an example of how I intend to call it. I'm open to suggestions for improvement on how to make it more idiomatic R. I'd like it to simply return a dataframe.